# How can I find as many scalar fields

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

how can I find as many scalar fields f: from R2 to R as possible which satisfy (d^2f)/(dxdy) = 0 for all r in R2?

I’ve tried this approach but am not sure if it is correct
Step 1: Integrate the given equation with respect to x.

∫((d^2f)/(dxdy)) dx = ∫0 dx

This gives us:

(df/dy) = g(y) + c1

where g(y) is an arbitrary function of y and c1 is the constant of integration.

Step 2: Integrate the result with respect to y.

∫(df/dy) dy = ∫(g(y) + c1) dy

This gives us:

f(x, y) = G(y) + c1*y + c2

where G(y) is the antiderivative of g(y) and c2 is another constant of integration

Comment: So you’re saying the only solutions are functions of $y$ only? Does this seem reasonable? Think about what constitutes a “constant of integration.”

Comment: Notice that $f(x, y) = x$ satisfies $f_{xy} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As you write, integrating with respect to $x$ gives
$$f_y(x, y) = \int_{x_0} f_{xy}(x, y) \,dx = \int_{x_0} 0 \,dx = C(y),$$ where $C(y)$ is the constant of integration with respect to $x$ and so is a function of $y$ alone.

Now integrating with respect to $y$ gives
$$f(x, y) = \int_{y_0} C(y) \,dy.$$
The error in your computation is here: Since we are integrating with respect to $y$, the constant of integration is a constant with respect to $y$, that is, is some function $g(x)$ of $x$ alone.

> The general solution is $$\boxed{f(x, y) = g(x) + h(y)},$$ where $h$ is an antiderivative of $C$.

> **Remark** In our computation we used that the domain of $f$ contained the line segment with endpoints $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(x_0, y)$ and the line segment with endpoints $(x_0, y)$ and $(x, y)$, so our solution is general for such sets with continuous second derivatives everywhere. This condition applies in particular to $\Bbb R^2$ and more generally if the domain of $f$ is convex (and hence locally). But if the domain is not convex, there may not be functions $g, h$ defined on all of the domain of $f$ such that $f(x, y) = g(x) + h(y)$.